# How can I find the highest number root of a number

Tags: python, for-loop, input, range, square-root

```
n = 64
#Find (root,power) 1 < power < 6

answer = None

for power in range(2,6):
    for root in range(2,6):
        if root ** power == n:
            answer = (root,power) 
            break
        elif root**power > n:
            break 
    if answer != None:
        break
print('The root',root,'and power =',power,'equals',n)
```

The root 4 and power = 3 equals 64

The answer spits out 4,3 ,but I would like it to give me 8,2 (The highest root possible)

Comment: outer loop should be root but counting down, since you want largest root.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 64
#Find (root,power) 1 < power < 6
answer = None
for root in range(n,2,-1):
    for power in range(2,6):
        if root ** power == n:
            answer = (root,power)
            break
        elif root**power > n:
            break 
    if answer != None:
        break
print('The root',root,'and power =',power,'equals',n)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to have correct code styling. Currently half of the code is outside of the code block it seems.

Comment: oops! My bad ,Thank you(Thijs van der Heijden)

Comment: Also, answers should come with an explanation of the code. Perhaps something like stark said in the comment: _"outer loop should be root but counting down, since you want largest root."_ Providing just code doesn't answer the asker's question, it just spoon-feeds them a solution.